# Django IntegrityError

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have a little project I am working. I am writing django database to hold some data. I have one ManyToManyField.

I am using my own Manager and adding methods for convience. I have one that adds different tasks to the users to do list. These items can be assigned to many people and so on.

When I do this I am getting an `IntegrityError` What is the main cause of this? The exact error I am getting is.

`...items_id may not be NULL`

I would appreciate answer on how to fix this. Also an explanation on how this exception is thrown. I have been told to catch it. But I dont like things being thrown unless they need to be.

Please and thank you!

Comment: Can you post the model and view in question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out all I needed to do was clean out my database with a `python manage.py sqlflush` Everything was fine afterwards. I then added south to help with migrations in the future.

**I would advise caution since `sqlflush` will return your database to back the state of the last syncdb.**

Answer (score 0):

Create and add items to the model before saving.